# How do you type a three lined equal sign that looks like a hamburger menu inside of a user.js file?

Tags: hamburger-menu, glyph, ligature

I am studying via tutorial, on email authentication. Inside the `user.js` file, there's an equal sign that looks like a hamburger menu. I have searched online and it talks about it on Wikipedia but I see no solution as to how to "type" the character in my code. The code inside of my `user.js` file looks like this:

```js
userScheama.methods = {
authenticate: function(plainText) {
return this.encryptPassword(plainText) <☰ symbol here> this.hashed._password;
},
```

Comment: I don't think you can type `☰`.  You might just have to copy/paste it in, but I'm still looking.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe it's the same as === but when you press enter depending on which code editor/extension you are using it will stay the same as === or look like a hamburger menu instead?